# What kinds of sets are added by Cohen forcing?

Tags: set-theory, forcing

I am trying to get a feel for what kinds of sets are added by forcing.  I apologize in advance, this question might be hard for me to put precisely into words.  Let's give a very simple example:

Let $\mathbb{P}$ be the set of all finite partial functions $p:\omega\to 2$, ordering by reverse inclusion.  If $G$ is a generic for $\mathbb{P}$ over $V$, then $F:=\bigcup G$ is the characteristic function for a cofinal subset of $\omega$, or alternatively a total function with an unbounded number of $0$'s and $1$'s.

In particular this set $X$ was not in the ground model.  Let's say the ground model is the universe I happen to live in.  So $F$ is distinct from any $\omega$-length sequence of 0's and 1's I could come up with!  This is where I'm fuzzy on things (for example "come up with" is vague and probably the critical issue), can anyone give me some intuition here to go on?

Comment: Welcome to Math.stackexchange! I hope you enjoy your stay! To get back to the question, it seems like you know exactly one set that was added. Maybe you could add to your question "what other sets are added (if any)" (I am not sure and would like to know too!)

Comment: Thanks for the warm welcome, Ryan!  What other sets are added has interested me for some time as well, but I suppose my question more asks what properties can/must such a set have (in particular, what sets it apart from ground model sets).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This question is pretty much the heart of forcing, but is also somewhat difficult to answer.  I'll stick with examples.  (If this is insufficient, leave comments and I'll attempt to improve.)

First of all, after adding $G$ (and thus $F$), since the extension also satisfies $\mathsf{ZF(C)}$, all sets definable from $F$ (and elements of the ground model $V$) are added.  Trivial examples are $\{ F \}$, $\{ \{ F \} \}$, $\langle F , \{ F \} \rangle$, etc.  The sets $F^{-1} [ \{ 0 \} ]$ and $F^{-1} [ \{ 1 \} ]$ are added.  For any $g \in {^\omega}2 \cap V$ you are going to add $F + g$ (pointwise addition modulo $2$).  The set of all such reals (functions) will also be added. (This last set is added because $V$ is a definable class in $V[G]$, so one can speak of $\{ F+g : g \in {^\omega}2 \cap V \}$ in the extension.)

Note that if any of these sets happened to belong to $V$, then one could use that set to show that $F$ is also an element of $V$.  ($F$ is the unique element of $\{F\}$. $F$ is the characteristic function of $F^{-1} [ \{ 1 \} ]$.  $F$ is $(F+g)-g$ for any $g \in {^\omega}2 \cap V$.)  This shows that these sets are necessarily *added*.

---

For *nontrivial* examples of sets added when adding a Cohen real, things get a little more complicated, and requires a finer analysis of the forcing to suss out.  I'll just give a couple of examples of *types* of sets added:

- In

  > J. Roitman, *Adding a random or a Cohen real: topological consequences and the effect on Martin's axiom*, Fund. Math. 103 (1979), no. 1, 47–60, [MR0535835](http://ams.org//mathscinet-getitem?mr=959438), [link](http://pldml.icm.edu.pl/pldml/element/bwmeta1.element.bwnjournal-article-fmv103i1p6bwm?q=bwmeta1.element.bwnjournal-number-fm-1979-103-1;5&qt=CHILDREN-STATELESS)

  it is proven that that adding a Cohen real also adds a subspace of ${^{\omega_1}}2$ with a particular property (it is a *strong L-space*).
- In

  > S. Shelah, *Can you take Solovay's inaccessible away?*, Israel J. Math. 48 (1984), no. 1, 1–47, [MR0768264](http://ams.org//mathscinet-getitem?mr=0768264)

  it is shown that adding a Cohen real adds a Souslin tree.

(Neither of the above objects can exist assuming $\mathsf{MA} + \neg \mathsf{CH}$, so when you add one Cohen real to a model of $\mathsf{MA} + \neg \mathsf{CH}$ you destroy Martin's Axiom.)

Comment: Destroy away: ‘Martin’s axiom is not something which excites D.A. Martin very much’. — Mary Ellen Rudin `:-)`

Comment: Thank you for your response, Arthur!  That does indeed help a lot.  So when you say definable, do you mean sets of the form $\{x \mid \varphi(x, F, v_1, ..., v_n)$ where each $v_i$ is from $V$?  Let me follow this up with a more pointed (and yet vague) question, can we add a set that has some effect on arithmetic?  For example, could one force to add an integer sequence that was a solution the Collatz conjecture?  I'm guessing not, and that absoluteness comes into play here.

Comment: @Murphy Your guess is correct; the truth of arithmetic statements (that is, statements about the first-order theory of the natural numbers with $+$ and $\times$, is not affected by forcing. A stronger result along these lines is  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absoluteness#Shoenfield.27s_absoluteness_theorem, which shows that most statements arising in "ordinary mathematics" cannot be proved independent by forcing.

Comment: @Murphy: For Collatz the case is quite strict. Note that the "Collatz" sequence of a number is recursively defined, and so as soon as you have the number, you also have its Collatz sequence.  But the set $\omega$ is absolute for transitive models of (a large enough fragment of) $\mathsf{ZFC}$, meaning that you cannot add natural numbers (for example, a counterexample to the Collatz conjecture) by forcing.

Comment: @Brian: Martin's Axiom may not excite Martin, but I've grown quite fond of PFA, so I sometimes need MA.  (I am, however, curious where that MER quote comes from.)

Comment: @ArthurFischer also, adding a Cohen real adds a Suslin tree.

Comment: @Camilo: And this was noted in the second bullet point of the second half of my answer.

Comment: @Arthur: I used MA a lot when it was bright and shiny, so I was quite fond of it. The quotation is from her *Lectures on Set Theoretic Topology*, CBMS Regional Conference Series in Mathematics Nr. $23$, $1975$. (I was one of the readers/proofreaders.)

Comment: @Brian: Now I see it!  For some unknown reason I did a cursory look through the _wrong_ Martin's Axiom chapter in her book before posting my comment.$\;\;$ _(redface)_ $\;\;$(She really wasn't too fond of the Moore Method if she let you read the proofs.$\;\;$;-)$\;\;$)

Comment: @Arthur: Ha. That was my last semester, and I’d already written up my dissertation over Christmas break. (I actually did have two courses, both in topology, that were taught mostly Moore method: one was my very first course in the subject, taught by John Greever at Harvey Mudd, and one was the first topology course at Madison, taught by Jim Cannon. Splendid course, both of them — at least for me.)